# PhoneGap CLI Error to Run or Emulate on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

I'm working my way through the getting started portion for PhoneGap here: (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). I'm attempting to run the cmd cordova run android which then produces the error: Error: EPERM, operation not permitted...

Has anyone else experienced this error with PhoneGap or a related process? I'm unable to run the emulator or install it to my device.

PhoneGap v: 2.9.1
OS: Win 8.1.x

Comment: You either should run the command as Admin user or grant the folders admin access. EPERM means that the program does not have rights to change the file/folder on your system.

Comment: The link of the doc you're following is about phonegap 3.5 and at the end of your post you say you use phonegap 2.9.1... Phonegap 3.x and 2.x are verry different, so maybe you should tell a little more about what you're really doing and what version of phonegap and cordova you really installed!

Comment: I must have missed something reading through all the documents on the site. I'll have to take a look at it again for the proper version and docs. @QuickFix

Comment: I was running all the commands as admin like you mentioned and even checked it on the directory itself. @frank

Answer (score 1):

for phonegap or cordova first you needed to setup environment variables...have you set up that ? if yes then pls let me see which path have you set up...
common path needed to setup are

variable : ANDROID_HOME 
value : C:\Android\sdk

variable : ANT_HOME 
value : C:\apache-ant-1.9.4

variable : JAVA_HOME 
value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

variable : PATH 
value : (npminstallationdirectory)AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ant\bin;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Android\sdk\tools\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;

this path are accoring to my side just confirm it that are already set and are proper according your side...

Comment: reason for negative marking ? you needed to note down reason...i have worked on phone-gap and i have got this type error most of time because of this and there is nothing wrong on this...and you not have putted any stack trace or error ...that i can provide you exact answer...again please explain your detail issue or tell the reason of negative marking...

Comment: I actually switched the order in how the path was setup and took out the %ant_home% and just put the path there instead. Works now. Thanks for the help. @user2800219

Comment: Glad it works for you if it really helps then mark as answer so other can refer this as solution (answer) of question and 
Happy Coding...